# Printing a 2500 x 2500 dimensional matrix using Perl

Tags: perl

I am very new to Perl. Recently I wrote a code to calculate the coefficient of correlation between the atoms between two structures. This is a brief summary of my program.

```
for($i=1;$i<=2500;$i++)
{
    for($j=1;$j<=2500;$j++)
    {
         calculate the correlation (Cij);
         print $Cij;
    }
}
```

This program prints all the correlations serially in a single column. But I need to print the correlations in the form of a matrix, something like..

```
         Atom1    Atom2   Atom3    Atom4
Atom1     0.5     -0.1     0.6      0.8
Atom2     0.1      0.2     0.3     -0.5
Atom3    -0.8      0.9     1.0      0.0
Atom4     0.3      1.0     0.8     -0.8
```

I don't know, how it can be done. Please help me with a solution or suggest me how to do it !

Comment: Trying printing newlines in your outer loop and using some form of whitespace in your inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple issue you're having. You need to print a NL after you finish printing a row. However, while i have your attention, I'll prattle on.

You should store your data in a matrix using [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). This way, the way you store your data matches the concept of your data:

```
my @atoms;       # Storing the data in here
my $i = 300;
my $j = 400;

my $value = ...; # Calculating what the value should be at column 300, row 400.

# Any one of these will work. Pick one:

my $atoms[$i][$j] = $value;    # Looks just like a matrix!
my $atoms[$i]->[$j] = $value;  # Reminds you this isn't really a matrix.
my ${$atoms[$1]}[$j] = $value; # Now this just looks ridiculous, but is technically correct.
```

My preference is the second way. It's just a light reminder that this isn't actually a matrix. Instead it's an array of my rows, and each *row* points to another array that holds the *column* data for that particular row. The syntax is still pretty clean although not quite as clean as the first way.

Now, let's get back to your problem:

```
my @atoms;  # I'll store the calculated values here

....

my $atoms[$i]->[$j] = ... # calculated value for row $i column $j

....

# And not to print out my matrix

for my $i (0..$#atoms) {
    for my $j (0..$#{ $atoms[$i] } ) {
       printf "%4.2f  ", $atoms[$i]->[$j];  # Notice no "\n".
    }
    print "\n";    # Print the NL once you finish a row
}
```

Notice I use `for my $i (0..$#atoms)`. This syntax is cleaner than the C style three part `for` which is being discouraged. (Python doesn't have it, and I don't know it will be supported in Perl 6). This is very easy to understand: I'm incrementing through my array. I also use `$#atom` which is the length of my `@atoms` array -- or the number of rows in my Matrix. This way, as my matrix size changes, I don't have to edit my program.

The *columns* `[$j]` is a bit tricker. `$atom[$i]` is a reference to an array that contains my column data for row `$i`, and doesn't really represent a row of data directly. (This is why I like `$atoms[$i]->[$j]` instead of `$atoms[$i][$j]`. It gives me this subtle reminder.) To get the actual array that contains my column data for row `$i`, I need to dereference it. Thus, the actual column values are stored in row `$i` in the array array `@{$atoms[$i]}`.

To get the last entry in an array, you replace the `@` sigil with `$#`, so the last index in my
array is `$#{ $atoms[$i] }`.

Oh, another thing because this isn't a true matrix: Each row could have a different numbers of entries. You can't have that with a real matrix. This makes using an Array of Arrays in Perl a bit more powerful, and a bit more dangerous. If you need a consistent number of columns, you have to manually check for that. A true matrix would automatically create the required columns based upon the largest `$j` value.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I exactly want to do. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Pseudo Code, you might have to take care of special cases and especially the headers yourself.

```
for($i=1;$i<=2500;$i++)
{
print "\n";  # linebreak here.
    for($j=1;$j<=2500;$j++)
    {
        calculate the correlation (Cij);
        printf "\t%4f",$Cij;  # print a tab followed by your float giving it 4
                              # spaces of room. But no linebreak here.
    }
}
```

This is of course a very crude and quick and dirty solution. But if you save the output into a .csv file, most csv-able spreadsheet programs (OpenOfice) should easily be able to read it into a proper table. If the spreadsheet viewer of your choice can not understand tabs as delimeter, you could easily add ; or / or whatever it can use into the printf string.

Comment: Oh! I just forgot ${Cij} concept. Thank you all for your solutions and suggestions.

Comment: You should probably still accept either of the answers to mark the question as finished. I would suggest the one by David W for its extensiveness.